# Chrome developer tools window dimensions are inconsistent

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

When you have the Chrome developer tools open, and you resize the window, a small white box appears in the top right corner telling you the dimensions of the window as you resize it. I've marked it with a big green arrow in the screenshot below.

This is a very useful tool, but I've noticed that frequently the values are unexpected and inconsistent with the widths of other elements. For example, when I took the screenshot below, Chrome says the window width is 419px. But if I click the `html` elements, whose width should be 100%, Chrome tells me **its** width is 404px. This is confusing to me. Why are they different? Is this a bug in Chrome?

[image: Chrome developer tools window size indicator]

Comment: Some browsers include the scrollbar & browser 'chrome' widths and some don't as I recall

Comment: @Paulie_D This would explain a difference between the width shown in Chrome vs another browser, but I'm describing a discrepancy between two elements in the same Chrome window. Are you suggesting that Chrome dev tools includes the scrollbar in some widths but not others?

Comment: Scrollbars such as these aren't part of the HTML but they do count for viewport sizes (the arrowed number) ...it's a curiosity, I agree.

Comment: Interesting. This theory is supported by the fact that the difference **appears** to be consistently 15px. Does that sound like the width of the Chrome vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Also, the width displayed by dev tools is different from what is displayed by jQuery using $('body').innerWidth() or $('body').width()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's including the vertical scroll bar's width. 
Try removing the scroll bar and then check. It will match exactly.

Comment: This was not the answer for me.  When small I see a 20px difference (HTML tag width is larger).  When I expand the width of the browser I see a 200px difference.  That's not a scrollbar.  For me there is a ~10% diff... I found elsewhere this was due to the BROWSER ZOOM setting.

Answer (score 16):

FYI those dimension numbers are `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight`.

[Robert](/users/5153063/robert) is correct. Make sure the zoom ratio is 100% to get the correct dimensions.

Comment: ZOOOOOM, that was it for me

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed that Chrome now displays a magnifying glass icon on the right side of the address bar when the zoom ratio isn't 100%.